# Why are the props onClose and onOpen marked as required in the SwipeableDrawer in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, material-ui

What I understand about the need of properties like `onOpen` and `onClose` is that they try to implement the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

So, why should a client of the `SwipeableDrawer` that doesn't want to *observe* those events provide values for those properties? In my case, for example, since I do not want to be an *observer*, I had to provide empty arrow functions as values.

What is the rationale for this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** an implementation of the Observer pattern. In the [API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/swipeable-drawer/#props) for `onOpen` it says the following:

> Callback fired when the component **requests** to be opened.

The key here is that it "requests" to be opened (but its open/close state has not changed), and you decide whether or not to change the state that you are passing in to the `open` prop. The same is true for the `onClose` prop. This allows you to inspect the details of the `event` in conjunction with other state within your app to decide whether or not the `open` state of the drawer changes.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense!

Comment: So, it is true that it is not an implementation of the Observer pattern, but after giving it some more thought, I still believe that there's no need to have them be required.

Comment: @alex Without them, there isn't any way for you to know whether or not the user has done an action that should trigger changing the `open` prop.

Comment: Without them it would be an UnswipeableDrawer.

Comment: Yes, there are: I just have to change the `open` prop somewhere else in my logic, for example, on the *click* event of a button (a cross at the top right corner of the drawer). The thing is that `open` is the ultimate truth for the drawer, so as long as I handle its state manually, I don't have to care about those events. Am I mistaken about something?

Comment: @alex You don't need **Swipeable**Drawer if you just want to control it with a button (just use `Drawer` which doesn't require those functions). `SwipeableDrawer` is watching for swipe actions on the document body in order to trigger the `onOpen` and `onClose` functions, so if you don't provide those functions then you aren't getting any of the functionality that `SwipeableDrawer` provides.